# Cyclic Error in Speculative Plan in Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting the below error if i put the below line in my code :

```
"MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" = format("@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=%s;SecretName=Webapp-FE-Secret)", module.key-vault.key_vault.self.name)
```

Error :

```
Error: Cycle: local.network_acls_ip_rules (expand), module.key-vault.var.key_vault_network_acls_ip_rules (expand), module.key-vault.azurerm_key_vault.default, module.key-vault.output.key_vault (expand), azurerm_app_service.fe, azurerm_app_service.api
```

I don't get this error if i don't put the above line

The full code for my Front End App Service is :

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "fe" {
  location            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  tags                = local.tags

  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.default.id
  name                = module.name_app_service_fe.location.app_service.name_unique
  identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }
  auth_settings {
    enabled                        = true
    default_provider               = "AzureActiveDirectory"
    issuer                         = format("https://sts.windows.net/%s/", data.azurerm_client_config.default.tenant_id)
    runtime_version                = "~1"
    token_store_enabled            = true
    unauthenticated_client_action  = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    allowed_external_redirect_urls = module.application_webapp_fe.application.self.reply_urls
    additional_login_params = {
      "response_type" = "code id_token",
      "resource"      = module.application_webapp_fe.application.self.application_id
    }
    active_directory {
      client_id         = module.application_webapp_fe.application.self.application_id
      client_secret     = module.application_webapp_fe.service_principal.secret.value
      allowed_audiences = []
    }
  }

  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    app_command_line         = ""
    default_documents        = []
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    ftps_state               = "Disabled"
    health_check_path        = ""
    http2_enabled            = true
    linux_fx_version         = "STATICSITE|1.0"
    local_mysql_enabled      = false
    managed_pipeline_mode    = "Integrated"
    min_tls_version          = "1.2"
    #pre_warmed_instance_count = 0
    python_version            = "3.4"
    remote_debugging_enabled  = false
    remote_debugging_version  = "VS2019"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = false
    websockets_enabled        = false
    windows_fx_version        = ""
    cors {
      allowed_origins     = []
      support_credentials = false
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER"     = "168.63.129.16"
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL" = "1"
     "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" = format("@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=%s;SecretName=Webapp-FE-Secret)", module.key-vault.key_vault.self.name)
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "site_config",
      "auth_settings"
    ]
  }
}
```

The Key Vault already has the secret name :

```
Webapp-FE-Secret
```

The value of the secret is the Service Principal of my Front End App registration

Below is the code for my Key Vault Module :

```
module "key-vault" {
  version   = "~> 1.0"
  source    = " xxxxx  "
  providers = { azurerm = azurerm, random = random }

  tenant_id             = data.azurerm_client_config.default.tenant_id
  resource_group_name   = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  key_vault_location    = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  key_vault_environment = var.project.environment.name
  key_vault_tags        = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.tags

  key_vault_name = substr(replace(var.project.name, "-", ""), 0, 16)

  key_vault_network_acls_ip_rules                   = concat(local.network_acls_ip_rules, module.project.azure.cidrs.global.contoso_enterprise_egress.all.coreinf)
  key_vault_network_acls_virtual_network_subnet_ids = [local.tfe_vnet_id]
  key_vault_secrets = {
    CosmosDB-PrimaryKey                          = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.primary_key
    CosmosDB-PrimaryReadOnlykey                  = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.primary_readonly_key
    CosmosDB-PrimaryKey-ConnectionString         = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.connection_strings[0]
    CosmosDB-PrimaryReadOnlykey-ConnectionString = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.connection_strings[1]

    StorageAccount-PrimaryKey                    = module.storageaccount.storage_account.self.primary_access_key
    StorageAccount-SecondaryKey                  = module.storageaccount.storage_account.self.secondary_access_key
    StorageAccount-ConnectionString-PrimaryKey   = module.storageaccount.storage_account.self.primary_connection_string
    StorageAccount-ConnectionString-SecondaryKey = module.storageaccount.storage_account.self.secondary_connection_string

    StorageAccount-FunctionApp-PrimaryKey                    = module.storageaccount-func-app.storage_account.self.primary_access_key
    StorageAccount-FunctionApp-SecondaryKey                  = module.storageaccount-func-app.storage_account.self.secondary_access_key
    StorageAccount-FunctionApp-ConnectionString-PrimaryKey   = module.storageaccount-func-app.storage_account.self.primary_connection_string
    StorageAccount-FunctionApp-ConnectionString-SecondaryKey = module.storageaccount-func-app.storage_account.self.secondary_connection_string

    Webapp-FE-Secret    = module.application_webapp_fe.service_principal.secret.value
    Webapp-API-Secret   = module.application_webapp_api.service_principal.secret.value
    Function-App-Secret = module.application_func_01.service_principal.secret.value

    frontendappid  = module.application_webapp_fe.application.self.application_id
    frontendappurl = module.application_webapp_fe.application.self.homepage
    frontendhost   = format("https://%s", azurerm_app_service.fe.default_site_hostname)

    appi-default-instrumentation-key = azurerm_application_insights.default["api"].instrumentation_key
    appi-default-app-id              = azurerm_application_insights.default["api"].app_id

    appi-default-fe-instrumentation-key = azurerm_application_insights.default["fe"].instrumentation_key
    appi-default-fe-app-id              = azurerm_application_insights.default["fe"].app_id

    functionappid  = module.application_func_01.application.self.application_id
    functionappurl = module.application_func_01.application.self.homepage
    functionhost   = format("https://%s", azurerm_function_app.default.default_hostname)

    webapiappid  = module.application_webapp_api.application.self.application_id
    webapiappuri = module.application_webapp_api.application.self.homepage
    webapihost   = format("https://%s", azurerm_app_service.api.default_site_hostname)
  }
}
```

The Local Blocks :

```
locals {
  network_acls_ip_rules = distinct(
    concat(
      formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_app_service.api.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)),
      formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_app_service.api.outbound_ip_addresses)),
      formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_app_service.fe.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)),
      formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_app_service.fe.outbound_ip_addresses)),
      formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_function_app.default.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)),
      formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_function_app.default.outbound_ip_addresses))
    )
  )
}
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this please.
The value : `"MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET` is already put manually in the Front End App and it is missing at the moment in TF state. So i want to include this in my code, so that Terraform doesn't wipe out everytime i do iterations on my code

Comment: Can you also add the `locals` block to the question?

Comment: Added the local block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By including this line:

```
"MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" = format("@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=%s;SecretName=Webapp-FE-Secret)", module.key-vault.key_vault.self.name)
```

You've created a cyclic reference, because the Front End app and the Keyvault have dependencies on each other (e.g. one can't be built before the other)

The cyclic reference happens because you also have these lines in `local.network_acl_ip_rules`

```
formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_app_service.fe.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)),
formatlist("%s/32", split(",", azurerm_app_service.fe.outbound_ip_addresses)),
```

So the front end app service needs to be created in order to populate those IP values, which are required to create the Keyvault. But the front end up can't be created because it needs the Keyvault name in the app settings.

Quick fix would be to hard code the Keyvault name in to the app setting.

Long term "fix" would be to update the `appsettings` or the `network_acls` outside of terraform using az cli or powershell script and call the script from terraform...